# Dual booting Lenovo Thinkpad X1 Windows 10 with Ubuntu Mate?

Tags: dual-boot, lenovo, mate

I just got a Lenovo Thinkpad X1 Gen 6, I am trying to dual boot it with Ubuntu Mate 18.04. I partitioned my drive while in windows, also disabled secure boot. Although when I boot into Ubuntu Mate from the flash drive to install it, I only have the option to erase and install ubuntu mate. I watched a video that showed that there should be an option to install along side windows 10 but I do not have that option. I also tried installing it "some other way" (I think that was the option) where it listed the different partitions to install although when I tried to install on the one that I wanted it on, it said there was no root directory.

Thank you
Please let me know if you need more information.

Answer (score 1):

If 'Install alongside Windows' option is missing, it's better to try out 'Something else'.
Here you have to manually format the new partition you have created.
You should atleast have the following two:

1) **Swap**: Select the partition and click on '+' symbol to add swap.
Allocate memory equal to your RAM size and select 'Swap' in use as option.

2) **Root**: Again click on '+' and use following configuration:

Size = Your remaining partition space

Type for the new partition = Primary

Location for the new partition = Beginning

Use as = EXT4 journaling file system

Mount point = /

Now continue with 'Install now'.

Refer these articles for more information:
https://www.tecmint.com/install-ubuntu-16-04-alongside-with-windows-10-or-8-in-dual-boot/

https://itsfoss.com/install-ubuntu-dual-boot-mode-windows/